# Angular JS change alert box to actual text on my document

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to modify someone's code that displays an alert if values don't match. Here's the code below:

```
if (finalData.length>0) {
                        $scope.rowCollection = finalData;
                        $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);
                    }
                    // $scope.rowCollection = $scope.rowCollection2;
                    else {
                        //$scope.rowCollection.push(finalData);
                        //alert('values are not matching Belinda');


                    }
                    $scope.showTable = true;
```

I'm trying to remove the alert and display 0 results found below a form on the document. Not sure if this even makes sense but would appreciate any help and would be able to answer any questions to get to the right direction.

TIA!

Atlante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign a variable in the html which will be set in the else part

in the html, where you want to display the message:

```
<span>{{$scope.resultsMsg}}</span>
```

and in your js

```
if (finalData.length>0) {
   $scope.rowCollection = finalData;
   $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);
}
// $scope.rowCollection = $scope.rowCollection2;
else {
   //$scope.rowCollection.push(finalData);
   //alert('values are not matching Belinda');
   $scope.resultsMsg = "0 results found.";
}
$scope.showTable = true;
```

2-way variable binding takes care of the rest in angularjs